# Jackson, inheritance, domain objects and generics

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I'm trying to code domain objects that can create themselves from other objects which implement the same interface.  I'm also coding it so they can transform themselves into other implementations, basically simple domain transfer objects.  I'm using jackson to automatically convert between implementations to reduce error prone boiler plate of manual object conversion.

It's probably easier to show with an example:

```
//base class
public abstract class DO<T extends Object> {
    public abstract T toDTO();
    public abstract DO<T> fromDTO(T t);
}

//concrete implementation
public class MyDO extends DO<MyDOInterface> implements MyDOInterface {

  public MyDO fromDTO(MyDTO r){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.convertValue(r, MyDO.class);      
  }

  public MyDTO toDTO() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.convertValue(this, MyDO.class);
  }

  //getters and setters from MyDOInterface
}
```

Now this works fine when creating DTOs, but is a bit of a pain the other way around.  To create my domain objects I'm having to do this:

```
MyDO myDO = new MyDO().fromDTO(aDTOInstance);
```

Which creates an empty object in order to call fromDTO(...) on it.

I've got a feeling I'm missing something simple that would either allow me to pass the DTO in a constructor or a static method to avoid this.  Or even a factory method in DO itself but I can't work out what it is.  Can anyone see a way of making this work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at `@JsonCreator` annotation: it allows you to mark constructors and (static) factory methods to be used. Specifically, so-called "delegating" creator like:
Another possibility when serializing would be `@JsonValue`, which allows certain conversions during serialization process.

I don't know if these help with specific problem, since you are doing more conversion than reading/writing JSON, but they seem related.

Comment: Cheers.  I do need to look more at how @JsonCreator works.  I've got to the point where it's working well with my specific domain objects (mongodb DBObjects) but I can't get a general solution to work.